# getting two different Hash key for app in facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Code :

```
// Add code to print out the key hash
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.my.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());

        Log.d("KeyHash1:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        Log.d("KeyHash2:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

    }
```

Logcat output :

```
02-21 10:07:55.957: D/KeyHash1:(2666): A0AFqS0kOUlvxvH1L3VCCrTXNY8=
02-21 10:07:55.967: D/KeyHash2:(2666): 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
```

I'm confuse with this two different hash key.
Now my question is that which key is right to use for my application

I think `md.digest()` return different value at 1st and 2nd method call.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, In log you are encoding the string.

this is mine code.

```
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
        sha1hash = md.digest();
```